# onclick on 2nd button,i want 1st as well as 2nd button to be get coloured

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have created 4 buttons. On click, it should change the color. I want is to, when I click on 2nd button, I want 1st button as well as 2nd button to be get coloured. How can i do it?

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
   
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';" value="2">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';" value="3">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';" value="4">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your javascript? and what does this have to do with php?

Comment: Remove the php tag, php wouldn't help with this since it's server-side.

Comment: @NoahCristino I believe you mean it's client side (in the user's browser) - or wait - do you mean *PHP* is server side?

Comment: @FKEinternet PHP is server side, but he needs something like javascript which is client side.

Comment: @NoahCristino yes, after I'd first posted my comment, I saw what you'd said from a different angle, which is why I added the "or wait" clause ;) When I first read your comment, I interpreted the "it" in "since it's server-side" as being the problem being discussed, but then I realized "it" was referring to PHP, not the problem - which made your comment totally correct.  It's sort of like looking at one of those optical illusion cubes - is the cube sticking out of the paper, or receding into it?  What you see depends on how you look at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `querySelector()` .need to trigger click event on first button on during second button click

**Updated**

1. added color `untill` clicked element

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
   var that =this;
  $('.button').each(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-color'));
    if(that == this){
   return false;
  }
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type="button" class="button" data-color="red" value="1">
  <input type="button" class="button" data-color="yellow" value="2">
  <input type="button" class="button" data-color="green" value="3">
  <input type="button" class="button" data-color="orange" value="4">
</body>
```

Comment: similarly ,if i click on 3 button,i want 1st,2nd,3rd button get coloured.And by clicking on 4th button i want  all button to be get coloured.how can i do???